# Oracle trigger whith an Insert loop

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle12c

i'm trying to create this trigger in Oracle 12c, but when i try to compile I obtain this error :pls-00382 expression is of wrong type cursor

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER INSERT ON BUDGETITEMS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
FOR I IN 
(select PARENTITEM
from BUDGETITEMS
where PARENTITEM is not null
START WITH item IN (:new.ITEM)
connect by prior PARENTITEM = ITEM) loop
INSERT INTO ITEMPARENTITEM_NEW ( ITEM, PARENTITEM, YEAR) VALUES ( :new.ITEM,I, :new.YEAR);
END LOOP;
END;
```

thanks for your help

This are my tables:

```
BUDGETITEMS

AMOUNT  NUMBER(2,0) Yes 
ITEMLEVEL   NUMBER  Yes 
ITEMNAME    VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)   No  
PARENTITEM  NUMBER  Yes 
YEAR    NUMBER(4,0) Yes 
ITEM    NUMBER  No  "BUDGET"."ISEQ$$_104999".nextval
```

AND

```
ITEMPARENTITEM_NEW

ITEM    NUMBER  No  
PARENTITEM  NUMBER  No  
YEAR    NUMBER(4,0) Yes
```

Comment: could you add table creation scripts to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to have the field:

```
I.PARENTITEM
```

Your insert should be:

```
INSERT INTO ITEMPARENTITEM_NEW ( ITEM, PARENTITEM, YEAR) VALUES ( :new.ITEM,I.PARENTITEM, :new.YEAR);
```

But I think you are introducing a mutation error.

Comment: See eg. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/what-are-the-causes-and-solutions-for-mutating-table-errors